# Problem in RViz?

Tags: rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i run RViz this msg appear to me and i can not solve it :

/home/eng/.rviz/display_config does not exist!

i use  fuerte
can one help me please ...

Thank you ....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135396/problem-in-rviz-!!/) by [M Samir](https://answers.ros.org/users/9326/m-samir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This warning only says that you have no saved rviz config. You can save you current config with File-> Save Config.

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2014-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1